# Cell shows different text on view and did select method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview having 4 sections.

```
    tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
         cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]; 
    }
```

It shows correct data. But when a cell is selected the text label shows wrong data even if on view it is displaying correct data.

```
tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Is the cell actually showing a different value on the screen when you select it or is it simply your `NSLog` statement that is showing an unexpected value?

Comment: NSLog is showing different value from the array.

Comment: Don't use the cell to get data. Use the data source based on the selected index path.

Comment: As i said, i have one row per section. But sections are not numbered sequentially. So a section at top might be section 3 containing item[0] from array. How to use data source then ?

Comment: The code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` states otherwise. The code to get the text in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` should be the same as the code to get the text in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. BTW - you are mistakenly implementing `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: whooo !! @rmaddy  This was the problem. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you implemented the wrong method. Implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.

Also, don't get data from the cell. Get it from the data source. You want:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"%@", [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]);
}
```